# I'm getting a stack overflow exception in my get method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

while I was refactoring my code, I got a System.StackOverflowException thrown by my **get** method when my view try to access a member of my class. 
That's the first time that I'm using the **?? (null-coalescing operator)** in c#.

That's my **model**:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Extranet45.Models
{
    public class Complaint
    {
        public string Nome
        {
            get => Nome ?? "Nome não informado.";
            private set => Nome = value ?? "Nome não informado.";
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get => Email ?? "Email não informado.";
            private set => Email = value ?? "Email não informado.";
        }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A denuncia não possui o texto obrigatório do seu conteúdo. (Corpo da Mensagem)")]
        public string Denuncia
        {
            get => Denuncia ?? "O texto da denuncia não foi encontrado.";
            private set => Denuncia = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("O campo denúncia é obrigatório.");
        }
        public Complaint() { }

        public Complaint(string nome, string email, string denuncia)
        {
            Nome = nome;
            Email = email;
            Denuncia = denuncia;
        }
    }
}
```

That's my **controller/action**:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Extranet45.Models;
using Utils;

namespace Extranet45.Controllers
{
    public class ComplaintController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Send");
        }

        // GET: Complaint/Send
        public ActionResult Send()
        {

            return View(new Complaint());
        }
    }
}
```

That's the *part of* my **view** where the exception is raised.

```
@model Extranet45.Models.Complaint

@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Denúncia";
    ViewBag.ShowHeader = false;
    ViewBag.BodyClass = "profile-page"; //Faz com que o header fique com a altura menor, porém ñão é uma solução elegante, refatorar
    ViewBag.HeaderImageUrl = "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit/blob/master/assets/img/city-profile.jpg?raw=true";

}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "Complaint", FormMethod.Post, new { @Class = "contact-form"}))
{
    <div class="section section-contacts">
        <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto">
            @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
            <h2 id="main-title" class="text-center title">Denuncie</h2>
            <h4 class="text-center description">Caso você tenha alguma reclamação ou precise comunicar algo incorreto ao Ceape, nos envie uma mensagem abaixo ou um email para <a href="mailto:denuncias@ceapema.org.br">denuncias@@ceapema.org.br</a></h4>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class=" form-group bmd-form-group">
                        <label for="textbox-nome" class="bmd-label-static">Nome - Opcional</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nome, new { @id = "textbox-nome", @Type = "Text", @Class = "form-control", name = "nome" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

More precisely at this line, when the view try to access the member **m.Nome**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nome, new { @id = "textbox-nome", @Type = "Text", @Class = "form-control", name = "nome" })
```

I don't know why my usage of null coalescing operator is causing an stack overflow.

Comment: `public string Nome
        {
            get => Nome ?? "Nome não informado.";` Every time you ask for `Nome` it goes and asks for `Nome`, and goes and asks for `Nome`, and goes and...

Comment: It's because your setter for Nome, Email, Denucia call themselves in an infinite process.

Comment: This is a really bad idea btw. If you write `x.Name = null;`, it should be `null` when called afterwards. And using localized strings is even worse.

Comment: @Groo Bad idea why? Brazil alone is huge, not every software needs localization

Answer (score 0):

It's because your setters for Nome, Email, Denucia call themselves in an infinite process. You can solve it by using  a backing field for each property.

```
   private string _nome ;

   public string Nome
    {
        get => _nome ?? "Nome não informado.";
        private set => _nome = value ?? "Nome não informado.";
    }

    private string _email; 

    public string Email
    {
        get => _email?? "Email não informado.";
        private set => _email= value ?? "Email não informado.";
    }

    private string _denucia;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A denuncia não possui o texto obrigatório do seu conteúdo. (Corpo da Mensagem)")]
    public string Denuncia
    {
        get => _denucia?? "O texto da denuncia não foi encontrado.";
        private set => _denucia= value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("O campo denúncia é obrigatório.");
    }
```